# Is there a way to determine why a Github workflow did or did not run based on triggers?

Tags: github, github-actions

We have a repo that includes a couple of workflows that include some conditions, such as path inclusion or exclusion.

When a PR or push is made to the repo, the workflows get evaluated, and based on the condition will either trigger or not. For example, a CI workflow could have:

```yaml
on:
  pull-request:
    branches:
      - main
    paths-ignore:
      - 'docs/**'
```

Because some conditions can be complex, I'm wondering if there's a way to determine why a particular workflow did or did not execute based on the event and conditions we have in the workflow.

Comment: Your question sounds too generic and can have any number of reasons why a workflow didn't trigger. if you can give a specific example and how the trigger look like, it will be easier to answer.

Comment: Your trigger points for workflow is incomplete, It runs on pull request raised on main branch only but when you merged the changes to main branch, your pipeline will not get triggered.

    on:
      push:
        branches:
          - main
      pull_request:

Answer (score 0):

Your trigger points for workflow is incomplete, It runs on pull request raised on main branch only but when you merged the changes to main branch, your pipeline will not get triggered.

```
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  pull_request:
```